# Changing the value of OG:IMAGE with jQuery click

Tags: jquery, image, facebook-opengraph

I just build up a image portfolio with a single HTML page where all the pictures are dynamically loaded. Everything works great so far, except for the facebook META OG:IMAGE.

Since the page loads just once, I can assign the OG:IMAGE URL once...
But I really would like to have each picture with its own OG:IMAGE, since this is a photo album.

The pics are loaded by clicking on a --li class="open-pic"-- tag.
I would like to change the OG:IMAGE value everytime I click on a --li class="open-pic"-- tag.

Is it possible?
I found stuff like this:

```
$('meta[name=og\\:image]').attr('content', newImageUrl);
```

However, I don't know how to link this to the li.open-pic onclick event.
Thank you!

G.

Answer (score 16):

> Since the page loads just once, I can assign the OG:IMAGE URL once... But I really would like to have each picture with its own OG:IMAGE, since this is a photo album.

Changing OG meta tags client-side is of no actual use – because Facebook will read those tags through it’s scraper, which means they will do an HTTP request for your URL and see what’s in the HTML code; and the scraper does not execute any JavaScript.

Solution: Provide an individual URL for each photo with its own meta information – and have your like button/share functionality/whatever FB feature point to that URL for each photo.

(How you handle things *client-side* does not matter – you can still display all the photos in one page, load new content via AJAX, whatever you like – but you *will* need separate URLs for your photos for them to be recognized as individual Open Graph objects.)

Comment: Thanks so much, CBroe! I really appreciate your clarification. I working on a wordpress environment, and after all, I will create a single page for each picture - there is no escape from that.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('li.open-pic').click(function(){
 $('meta[name=og\\:image]').attr('content', newImageUrl);
});
```

Comment: Ouch... So simple. I am ashamed of myself. Thanks so much.

Comment: no need for thankx :).. please dont forget to mark as answer or upvote if this helped. this might help others too

Comment: I believe this does not work ... yes it will change the value of the meta tag ... but it's useless because facebook will still show the original image that was registered in the meta tag ... see CBroe's answer ...

Comment: I think you need use $('meta[property="og:image"]') insted of  $('meta[name=og\\:image]')

Answer (score 4):

It's the colon. Try using single quote & double-quotes like this:

```
var imgSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src'); // image stored as variable
$('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content', imgSrc); // assigns meta property
```