# Error showing og:image

Tags: javascript, facebook, datalife-engine

I have problem with og:image in my website. og:image is displayed correctly only if I'm logged into their website sharethis.com with my facebook account. If I'm not logged in og:image picke some random image from my website.

I'm using DataLife Engine 10.1 and applied this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("head").append('<meta property="og:image" content="[xfvalue_slika]" />');
});
</script>
```

Only when I'm logged into their website, image in tag [xfvalute_slika] is displayed when I share news on facebook. When I logout and try to share again, og:image choose some random image from website and display.

Even if I look at source code, the image path is taken correctly but not displayed on facebook. As previous said random image is shared on facebook wall.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404868/changing-the-value-of-ogimage-with-jquery-click/12405500#12405500

Comment: I allready have working og:image but it's only displayed when you're logged into their websiste: sharethis.com. Something need to be changed into their script, those hashtags, securities.