# Share an image file on facebook with share dialogue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am making an app where a user uploads and manipulates a photo, and then can share it on facebook. For now I am trying to avoid a server, so that you users don't have their own page (which would be easy to share...)

I am saving the photos to Amazon s3 and my attempt was to change the open graph meta property to have the photo url before opening the share dialogue, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
s3UploadPicture(bucket, canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0), fbFileName, function(data){
  $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content', data.Location)

  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: window.location.href
  }, function(response){})
})
```

Is there any way to manipulate the crawler that gathers the data of the page?

Comment: You can not set the meta tags client-side via JS, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12405500/1427878 // The Feed dialog still allows you to specify those values at runtime; but you need an HTTP(S) URL for the image, a data URI won’t work. Your other alternative would be to make an actual photo upload via API (but that’ll get a bit more complex.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the photo upload? I couldn't find a simple way to do it

Comment: You would need to send the data as `multipart/form-data`, just as a form with a normal file upload field would. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating // But since you are uploading your image to S3 anyway, you should have a publicly reachable URL for it afterwards, right?

Comment: @CBroe Actually, I need to post the manipulated photo on fb and have a link only to the original on s3, so they are not connected. Where does the file data go in the request? I see only `"url": "{image-url}"` in the docs

Comment: You provide the image data via the `source` parameter.

Comment: Got it. Any chance you might know how to make the file data uploadable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845623/uploading-a-canvas-image-to-facebook-as-blob-of-multipart-form-data-type